# Quoted string with a backslash with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

The following code

```
text = QuotedString(quoteChar="(", endQuoteChar=")", escChar="\\")
text.leaveWhitespace()

def test_hex_with_backslashN_code(self):
    self.assertEqual(text.parseString("(\x01\x0a)")[0], "(\x01\x0a)")
```

triggers an exception:

```
ParseException: Expected quoted string, starting with ( ending with ) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

because of "\x0a" hexa value which is interpreted as '\n' and is not taken into account as a normal character even with the leaveWhitespace call.

I also tried with SkipTo but I didn't manage to handle escaped inner brackets like:

```
"( I am \( John \))"
```

with a parser

```
text = "(" + SkipTo(")")
```

Any idea how to fix/work around that?

Comment: Show your full code. I suspect that you are parsing strings and those slashes get interpreted before reaching `pyparsing`.

Comment: So, yeah, I was right, see my answer.

Comment: Also, please, show your parser code. I'm sure you have the same mistake there.

Comment: Then I probably don't get what your goal is… You either work with actual characters (that is, `\n`, for example) or you work with slashes and hex numbers.

Comment: So, I suggest you make a cup of tea, think again about your problem/task and update your question with more precise statements. Because it's really not clear what are your input strings, and what you want to do with them.

Comment: should be a bit clearer now

Answer (score 2):

Try prefixing your strings with `r`. That is if you have a string

```
"(\x01\x0a)"
```

change it to

```
r"(\x01\x0a)"
```

What happens is that slashes get interpreted right away and don't reach `pyparsing`. You have `text.parseString("(\x01\x0a)")` and it's *exactly* the same as `text.parseString("(\x01\n)")` .

Comment: The problem is not to have "\n" in the input string but the fact that prevent quotedString from parsing the input correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I finally found:

```
escaped_paren = Literal("\(") | Literal("\)")
text = "(" + SkipTo(")", ignore=escaped_paren)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, which addresses the backslash problem that kirelagin identified:

```
text = QuotedString(quoteChar="(", endQuoteChar=")", escChar="\\", unquoteResults=False)

print text.parseString(r"(\x01\x0a)")
assert(text.parseString(r"(\x01\x0a)")[0] == r"(\x01\x0a)")
```

Prints:

```
['(\\x01\\x0a)']
```

Since you assumed that the quoting characters would be included, add the argument `unquoteResults=False`. If you are going to strip off the ()'s anyway, might as well let pyparsing do it for you, and pass this argument as True (or just leave it out, since True is the default value).